# Are there standardized measures to characterize the volatility skew?

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, stochastic-volatility, volatility-smile, volatility-surface

Might be too simple a question, but I saw in Gatheral & Jacquier (2014) that commonly used features to match volatility skews are (and then I subsequently ChatGPTed some commonly used industry metrics):

- Level - such as the ATM IV
- Skew - such as the RR and Butterfly Spreads
- Curvature - such as the "Volatility Ratio", which refers to the ratio of IV of other options relative to the ATM IV. I guess the point of this ratio is to look at multiple ratios to analyze the how curved the whole skew is, which is a step up from the RR.

My question is, are there standardized metrics used by volatility quants in the industry? I am currently working with an equity volatility skew and wanted to get some useful summary statistics to analyze my dataset (beyond the simple mean, SD, kurtosis, upper/lower quantiles etc.).

Also, a more specific question would be to probably analyze if the SVI-JW is a good fit for fitting my equity volatility skew. However, since Gatheral & Jacquier (2014) do fit their methodology to SPX options, I would expect that the SVI-JW method is a naturally good choice.

Comment: I'm actually looking into something like this too, and historical principal components of implied vol surfaces seem promising https://math.stanford.edu/~papanico/pubftp/jfds.2020.1.032.full.pdfhttps://math.stanford.edu/~papanico/pubftp/jfds.2020.1.032.full.pdf

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, is there a new link to the paper you quoted? This one doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Apologies, try https://math.stanford.edu/~papanico/pubftp/jfds.2020.1.032.full.pdf

Comment: also seem worth reading https://doi.org/10.1080/1350486X.2023.2277960 ,  https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-1214-0_8 , simple tutorial https://medium.com/quantitative-insights/understanding-volatility-performance-with-pca-b89f797f3237